# Захват неактивного окна (linux, plasma)

Tags: screenshots, pixmap

Нужно делать скриншот неактивного окна (которое в данный момент минимизированное, допустим, или на соседнем виртуальном рабочем столе. каждые 5 секунд).
Слышал, что в окружение Enlightenment это возможно.
Хочу сделать, что-бы это было возможно в KDE.
Как я понял, в аттрибутах окна существует флаг map_state, на который смотрят проги для захвата скриншота, и что логично, должен существовать сам pixmap.

Можно ли как то пересобрать kde и прикрутить данную фичу? Точнее, пересобрать я знаю как, но вот с поиском "нужного участка кода" проблема. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. По исходникам выяснил, что для x-сессии у kwin в теле [updateVisibility](https://github.com/KDE/kwin/blob/d36e326d66d0d24c342b6f15cb5ef0a602cc2328/x11client.cpp#L1520) имеется проверка на настройки композита, в том числе просмотра миниатюр окон с различными состояниями (будь то минимизированное, на другом рабочем столе, или в другом активити).Соответственно, можно ничего не пересобирать, а зайти в SystemSettings->Display And Monitors->Compositor и выставить нужный чекбокс Keep window thumbnails в Always, после чего map_state у окон всегда будет IsViewable и можно делать скриншоты! =) Удачи.

Comment: ответ свой примите

Answer (score 1):

Картинку можно получить

```
xwd -id <windowid> | convert xwd:- image.png
```

cобытие сворачивания можно отследить

```
xprop -spy -id <windowid>
```

Надо как-то успевать получить изображение до того как оно погрузится ниже rootwin.

Comment: И что это меняет? Вы вопрос читали мой? Это не сработает для свёрнутого окна.

Comment: Дико извиняюсь. Не специально. сейчас попытаюсь написать код.

Comment: Меня мало интересует как отследить события сворачивания, потому что скрин нужно таскать с неактивного окна, а не c активного. =) Спасибо.

Comment: Уважаемый, если бы мне была более знакома подсистема иксов и как с ней взаимодействуют оконные менеджеры, то, найти в исходниках kwin, нужный кусок кода, думаю не составило бы труда.  (но это не точно) Вам ничего уже писать не нужно, я всё понял, что вы хотели донести. Спасибо за то, что уделили время моей проблеме.